# Starting up Windows occasionally fails and the computer emits a sound

Tags: windows

I have a Dell Inspiron core i-3 3521, processor core i3 3227u CPU 1.9 ghz, 4GB RAM, and a 500gb hard with the operating system Windows 7 ultimate.

A few days ago, I had an issue with the startup of my laptop.  When I press the start button, sometimes my Windows doesn't start but a blank page with 2-3 line appears on the screen with the sound like "toooo tooo tooo too...". This process repeats after continuously restarting until I wait until after closing down the lid and wait for 5- 10 mins and after that Windows starts normally

I have checked all of my software, and everything is fine. This is the only issue.  Can someone help me out, what is this?

Comment: You have some kind a power issue , your computer starts fine after discharging its power completely ( motherboard components) , what you should try is , before starting your computer , disconnect all power cables , press the start button for about 30 sec and start it again then tell me the results.

Comment: The _sound_ you are hearing is probably a _beep code_ that's generated when the systems fails POST (Power On Self Test).    Next time get the EXACT text that appears on the screen and count the beeps.  With those 2 pieces of information you can get help, as written tho nobody can answer this question.